# Is it possible to rewrite URL on the Server instead of the Client using the IIS Rewrite-Module

Tags: iis, module, url-rewriting

As I've described in my Title, I want to rewrite a certain URL not on the client-side who calls the URL but on the Server, so the request gets received by the locally (as Windows Service) running REST API.

[image: Click here for my Rewrite-Rules]

Is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: Instead of showing a screenshot with little information, please open the configuration file (applicationHost.config or web.config) and cut/paste the actual XML elements for the rules into the question.

Answer (score 0):

> We can use RewritePath method of HttpContext.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"] == "/Home")
        {
            Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.RewritePath("/Index.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```